# Phonegap: Canvas is not refreshing properly

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, phonegap-plugins

I am doing an android application in Phonegap. In canvas I made a moving image by touching.I tested in the device having different versions

when I run 4.1, 4.2 or 4.3 the image getting duplicating while moving.all other version is fine

i try by applying canvas background color and opacity, but still duplicating

is there any solution for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the appropriate code

Comment: its cause of android version. it not working in jelly bean @Eric

Answer (score 1):

i check the application 4.0,4.1,4.2,4.3 and 4.4

only this problem in jelly bean

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
         canvas.style.opacity = 0.99;
         setTimeout(function() {
            canvas.style.opacity = 1;
         }, .01);
```

This code is working perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is really a cause of the RAM memory. You are trying it on a different device, so there may be a differente result.

My advice is to implement a clearing function and call it after the movement .. but it's very difficult to say anything relevant when you didn't provide any working code or sample.

Comment: sorry.. its not because of ram, its cause of android version. it not working in jelly bean. did you know any solution to work in jelly bean @Samuel Ondrek